# How can I set only PDF417 scanning on Android vision?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision

I want that the Google API only recognizes PDF417 barcodes.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
BarcodeDetector detector = 
    new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                       .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.PDF417)
                       .build();
```

See the codelab [here](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#1) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful.